# jquery selector function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can find in the documentation what means the following instruction:

```
$(".myClass", elem).click(...)
```

where *elem* is declared like this:

```
var elem = $("#someTableElement tbody")
```

Comment: [did you try reading the jQuery API before asking here?](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

Comment: I was looking in the selector section, then some seconds before the answer I found it... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means find ".myClass" within `elem` context. In other words it's equivalent to

```
$(elem).find(".myClass").click(...);
```

> I can find in the documentation what means the following instruction

And the best place to look for when documentations search fails, is source code. This specific behavior is defined in [`jQuery.fn.init`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a644101ed04d0beacea864ce805e0c4f86ba1cd1/src/core/init.js#L90) method, and it states literally this:

```
// HANDLE: $(expr, context)
// (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
} else {
    return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );
}
```